# second level menu NSView to link NSMenuItem problems

Tags: swift, nsview, nsmenuitem

The first and second level menus are matched one by one through the NSmenuItem's title invocation array, and the first level menu also works properly to display data.
But once the secondary menu into NSView, only the first item will be show the data, the rest are blank, tried a lot of methods, did not succeed, please guide me, how to deal with?

update method:

```
    func updateData() {
        for city in cites {
            let airQualityApi = AirQualityApi()
            airQualityApi.fetchData(query: city, success: {airQuality in
                if let airQualityMenyItem = self.statusMenu.item(withTitle: city){
                    airQualityMenyItem.title = airQuality.description
                    self.airQualityDetailView.update(airQuality: airQuality)
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

Sec level NSView update method:

```
    func update(airQuality: AirQuality) {
        DispatchQueue.main.sync {
            self.cityName.stringValue = airQuality.city
            self.airQuality.intValue = Int32(airQuality.aqi)
            
        }

    }
```

add NSMenuItem:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
        updateData()
        let icon = NSImage(named: "icon")
        icon?.isTemplate = true
        if let button = statusItem.button {
            button.image = icon
        }
        statusItem.menu = statusMenu
        
        //let editMenuItem = NSMenuItem()
        //editMenuItem.title = "showAqi"
        for i in 0 ... cites.count - 1 {
            let mainMenu = NSMenuItem(title: cites[i], action: .none, keyEquivalent: "")
            statusMenu.insertItem(mainMenu, at: i)
            let sub = NSMenu()
            let subMenu = NSMenuItem(title: mainMenu.title, action: .none, keyEquivalent: "")
            subMenu.view = airQualityDetailView
            //print(subMenu.title)
            statusMenu.setSubmenu(sub, for: mainMenu)
            sub.addItem(subMenu)
            
            //sub.insertItem(subMenu, at: 0)
            
        }
        
    }
```

you can see the integral code here  [the whole project code on GitHub](https://github.com/milleyin/focusWeather)

thank you soooooo much

Comment: Please describe what you're trying to acomplish, a menu with submenus? Which item do you want to change? Can you give an example?

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I would like to implement a two-level menu, the first level using NSMenuItem implementation, the second level of the menu using NSView implementation, the first level of the menu to display simple air quality, the second level to display weather data, the two levels of menu associated with the city name, the first level of the menu to display the air quality, the second level of the menu to display the weather data.

Comment: The problem we're having is that if the first and second level menus are both NSMenuItem, then there's no problem with the association. In the first and second level menus, the cities are one-to-one, but if I use NSView in the second level menu, then submenu.view, as I've coded it, so that only the first city is shown in the second level menu. The others will only show the view but no data.
You can see the whole project at the github address I left above.

Comment: Each menu item must have its own view, they can't share `airQualityDetailView`.

Comment: Oh, I see, so if I want to use the NSView on a secondary menu to correspond one by one by city name to a primary menu. What ideas should I use to do this? Variable number of primary and secondary menus